# Warning when using dsp:include on jsp

Tags: include, uri, warnings, atg

> The current request URI does not match the URI last updated for dsp:page (XXX.jsp?XXX != XXX.jsp). This may result in out of order or lost content by the attempt of dsp:include to include 'XXX.jsp'. Please make sure the contents of each JSP page containing a dsp tag are wrapped with dsp:page.

This message is showing up as a warning in the logs when I try to use dsp:include on certain jsp pages of our ATG mobile application.

I am working with an older codebase and have scanned through all the surrounding included jsps and they are all correctly wrapped with "dsp:page"

The AssemblerPpelineServlet grabs the RequestURI and obtains the forwardURL from the cache appending a querystring. This causes an apparent mismatch.

I cannot find any reference to this warning message anywhere and would be greatful if anyone could provide any insight.

Comment: Do you have an static includes (ie. non `<dsp:include>`) that contains a `<dsp:page>` tag?

Comment: @radimpe The include tags for the fragments above and below the one showing the warning are both using salf-closing jsp:include with no parameters. I tried chaning these to dsp:include and the warning was then just given for all three. There were some lingering jsp:includes in nested pages which have also been removed and the issue is still occurring.

Comment: I found the cause of this issue. Certain jsp pages included a breadcrumb fragment jsp. This jsp was changing the changing the request with line `<dsp:setvalue bean="/OriginatingRequest.requestURIHasQueryString" value="true" />`.